# ASP.NET Core precompiled views on publish

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

I've previously created an ASP.NET Core project with .NET Core 2.0 preview 1 and Visual Studio 2017 15.3 preview. Just the default stuff from the project template, no custom code yet. Then I used the Publish command and have everything copied to the directory bin\Release\PublishOutput. All nice and good. 5 MB, can be deployed to the production web server and it works.

Now I've tried the same thing with VS Code and just won't get anywhere. I created the project with `dotnet new mvc` and opened it in VS Code with `code .`. After closing and opening it a few times and editing .cs files, I think I've now jumped over all the hurdles that VS Code comes with. I can run the application locally.

But the publishing doesn't quite produce the desired result. I run `dotnet publish -c Release` manually because VS Code doesn't seem to offer anything here. I get tons of files in bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0, along with a subdirectory called publish. Both have a copy of MySite.dll and MySite.pdb, but no precompiled views DLL. Also, the publish directory has 54 MB of runtime DLLs that weren't required for what Visual Studio gave me.

What is the intended method to publish an ASP.NET Core MVC application with VS Code? Everything is the latest version, downloaded and installed today.

Do I need components from the full Visual Studio to get the complete publishing experience, with all the advertised features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I have recently discovered in ASP.NET Core 2.0 preview 2 that this has been resolved. A project created with `dotnet new mvc` has the `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` property set in the csproj file, and `dotnet publish` does the same as publishing through Visual Studio 2017 (15.3) now.