# How to dotnet publish with precompiled views for a non portable target?

Tags: build, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have this script:

```
# common paths
$buildFolder = (Get-Item -Path "./" -Verbose).FullName
$slnFolder = Join-Path $buildFolder "../"
$outputFolder = Join-Path $buildFolder "build"
$webMvcFolder = Join-Path $slnFolder "ConversioIt.Conmania"

# clear existing folder
Remove-Item $outputFolder -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore
New-Item -Path $outputFolder -ItemType Directory

# restore nuget
Set-Location $slnFolder
dotnet restore

# publish
Set-Location $webMvcFolder
dotnet publish --output (Join-Path $outputFolder "Portable")
dotnet publish --output (Join-Path $outputFolder "Win") -c Release -r win-x64
dotnet publish --output (Join-Path $outputFolder "Linux") -c Release -r linux-x64
dotnet publish --output (Join-Path $outputFolder "OSX") -c Release -r osx-x64
pause
```

My portable output (the first `dotnet publish`) does precompile the views.

However my Windows, Linuxs and OSX builds do not precompile the views. Instead I get the `Area`folder with all the views in the publishing output.

I also set the `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` property per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485562/asp-net-core-precompiled-views-on-publish):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Which does nothing change. I also use the AspNetCore.All Metapackage (2.0), which should automaticly define everything needed for precompilation, if I understood it correct?

So how can I make a standalone build (Which is runnable without .net, e.g. Linux/Win builds) to precompile the views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Razor view precompilation is currently unavailable when performing a [self-contained deployment (SCD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) in ASP.NET Core 2.0. The feature will be available for SCDs when 2.1 releases. For more information, see [View compilation fails when cross-compiling for Linux on Windows](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/102).